# java base class that extends a paramater class/interface

Tags: java, multiple-inheritance

I have some base class `Entity`. I want to allow users of `Entity` to create instances of `Entity` that extend some given super class T (as if `Entity`s declaration was `Class Entity extends T`). I'm not aware of what T actually is, so I want `Entity` to be modular in that respect. If that's not possible I'm ok with `Entity` implementing a given interface T as well.

Things like `public class Entity<T> extends T` and `public class Entity<T> implements T` do not work. ("Cannot refer to the type parameter T as a supertype").

So my questions are:

1) is this at all possible to achieve in java ? some other language ?

2) if so, how ?

3) usually when java puts up hurdles like that it means something is wrong with my design, so how would you create this functionality (I guess what I'm looking for is basically multiple inheritance from Entity and T, can this be done ?).

EDIT: clarification - I want to achieve [mixin](http://csis.pace.edu/~bergin/patterns/multipleinheritance.html) type behavior while requiring as little as possible from the caller (creating a subclass of T which delegates calls to an Entity instance would demand way too much from the caller). is there no other way to do this ?

Comment: Yes, this doesn't make sense in Java. What could it mean for a class to extend an arbitrary class? Are you looking for mixin- type behaviour?

Comment: In question 1, why do you ask "[is this possible in] some other language?".  Isn't this really meant to be a `Java` question?

Comment: I'd try putting together an interface of the minimal amount of attributes and methods required by any superclass that you want to inject, and then have `Entity` implement the given interface. If you need something more complicated than that, then you'll probably need to set up a factory of some kind.

Comment: @JackManey I'm not above setting up a factory, just not sure of exactly how to go about it. I cannot require changes in the super classes and cannot know them in advance.. I just want to be able to create an instance of the superclass that also has my concrete `Entity`s functionality..

Comment: @OliCharlesworth yes I want to achieve mixin type behavior while requiring as little as possible from the caller (creating a subclass of T which delegates calls to an `Entity` instance would demand way too much from the caller). is there no other way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java doesn't support multiple inheritance; a given class can't be a direct subclass of more than one *class*.

However, if `Entity` is an *interface*, you can do it using an *intersection bound*.

For example, to code a method that accepts an instance that is a subclass (not necessarily a direct subclass) of `SomeClass` and that implements `Entity`:

```
public <T extends Entity & SomeClass> void doSomething(T t) {
}
```

Comment: but Entity is not and can not be an interface. it has concrete functionality that I wish to append to other arbitrary classes..

Comment: Composition and Annotation Processing are probably your.best option

Comment: ah. annotation processing seems promising. I'll give it a try. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
template <class A>
class B : public A
{
```

Possible in C++ at least.

I have used this once in my own work, to add behavior to two classes that are very closely related (one inheriting from the other). It struck me only much later that the [Decorator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) might have worked as well. Perhaps you can also consider it.

Comment: My guess (I didn't down vote you) is that you answer a fraction of question 1 only -- and the fraction that's not particularly useful.

Comment: @GregKopff: fair enough.. but it is atleast a part answer and in no way wrong.. doesnt merit a downvote in my book.

Answer (score 0):

No thats not how it works in Java. You might want to consider composition instead of inheritance.

I'm kind of reading between the lines here, but are these Entities in a game engine? A component system would work well...

http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/component.html

Here's a quick example...

```
class Entity {
    List<Component> components;

    void update() {
        for(Component component: components) {
            component.update(this);
        }
    }
}

interface Component {
    void update(Entity parent);
}

class MovementComponent implements Component ...
class AnimationComponent ...
class BehaviourComponent ...
```

Comment: +1 for reading between the lines. but its actually part of a library that's supposed to complement existing game engines. existing game engines usually have some concrete `Entity` class of their own. I wanted to allow users of the library to create instances of their game engines `entity`s that also have the functionality of my `Entity` class..

Answer (score 0):

The key in your question is when you said that you want to "create instances of Entity that extend some given super class T". An object (instance of a class) never extends a class. Only classes extend other classes.

What you probably want is to use interfaces. Let Entity be an interface and create classes that implement Entity and then instantiate those classes.